# How to find out the type of encoding in fiddler response body?

Tags: fiddler

[fiddler response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHYLj.png)

when I click the decode I get the decoded message, but where can I find the type of encoding so I can decode the message manually or for further info purposes?

Comment: man I wish I knew

Answer (score 0):

I am using fiddler version : v5.0.20204.45441 for .NET 4.6.1

I can see the encoding method when I click on Headers.

[image]

In my case encoding technique used is Gzip (Refer attached image). You can try it for your response and get the correct encoding method.

Correct path is :

Response body --> Headers --> Entity --> Content-Encoding.